# Elixir: error when piping to a function the result of inline comprehension

Tags: elixir

I've noticed something surprising with Elixir's `for` comprehensions when used to pipe the results into a function.

For example, these forms work:

```
foo = fn(list) ->
  for n <- list do
    n + 1
  end
  |> Enum.reverse
end

foo.([1,2,3])
# [4, 3, 2]

foo = fn(list) ->
  for(n <- list, do: (n + 1))
  |> Enum.reverse
end

foo.([1,2,3])
# [4, 3, 2]
```

But this doesn't, as it considers the `|> Mod.func` on the second line part of the `do` block of the macro:

```
foo = fn(list) ->
  for n <- list, do: n + 1
  |> Enum.reverse
end

foo.([1,2,3])
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for 2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1: Enumerable.impl_for!/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:116: Enumerable.reduce/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1636: Enum.reduce/3
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:228: :erl_eval.expr/5
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1623: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
```

I would guess that is has to do with how macros are expanded and their value returned, but interestingly these work:

```
bar = fn(list) ->
  if true, do: list
  |> Enum.reverse
end
bar.([1,2,3])
# [3, 2, 1]


bar = fn(list) ->
  if true, do: Enum.map(list, &(&1 + 1))
  |> Enum.reverse
end
bar.([1,2,3])
# [4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because of:

> warning: you are piping into a function call without parentheses,
>   which may be ambiguous. Please wrap the function you are piping into
>   in parentheses.

This works:

```
iex()> foo = fn(list) ->
...()> (for n <- list, do: n + 1)
...()> |> Enum.reverse
...()> end
#Function<6.52032458/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex()> foo.([1,2,3])
[4, 3, 2]
```

without parentheses your function like:

```
foo = fn(list) ->
  for n <- list, do: n + 1 |> Enum.reverse
end
```

and `n + 1` isn't a `list` so `(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for 2`

Comment: It worth to mention that OP’s `if true, do: list |> Enum.reverse` works because in this case the precedence/execution order does not change a thing.

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks, good point. Also, that just returns the `list`, without iteration.

Comment: Still, I don't think that this really answers my question. I know that wrapping in parenthesis the `for` macro solves the problem (what you did is very similar to one of my working examples). My confusion comes from the `|>` forward-pipe ignoring the new line. I thought that new lines are meaningful, but with the inline keyword-list form the new line is just ignored.

Comment: I don not get what exctly is surprising you. `|>` has the topmost preceding order, that’s why it is applied first. `n + 1` evaluates to 2 and `2 |>` fails. Why do you expect any other behavior?

Comment: Ok, thanks for mentioning the precedence order of the operators. I'm surprised because the new line is ignored. I would expect `\n` to separate independent statements. Apparently that doesn't happen.