# Elixir how do you sort a list comprehension?

Tags: sorting, elixir, list-comprehension

I have been struggling with sorting this list comprehension for a while now, and I don't understand two specific things about it.

```
for x <- span(2, n), y <- span(2, n), x <= y, x * y <= n, into: [], do: x * y
```

What it does is create a list of all non-primes up to n. Now if I try:

```
for x <- span(2, n), y <- span(2, n), x <= y, x * y <= n, into: [], do: x * y
  |> Enum.sort


for x <- span(2, n), y <- span(2, n), x <= y, x * y <= n, into: [], do: x * y   
  |> Enum.sort()
```

Both methods give me the error:

```
protocol Enumerable not implemented for 4
```

So my first question is how do you sort a comprehension using pipes?

EDIT:: Removed due to duplicates being present and my not noticing them =>

If I try:

```
comps = for x <- span(2, n), y <- span(2, n), x <= y, x * y <= n, into: [], do: x * y
Enum.sort(comps)
```

The list is sorted, but now it shows duplicates in the list.
  My second question is why does the output of the comprehension contain    duplicates if I store it in a variable and not contain them otherwise?

That seems like a rather arbitrary interaction.

Comment: What is `span`? You can do `for(x <- .., ...) |> Enum.sort` but it's not possible that you didn't have duplicates in the first snippet and you have it in the last one. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Dogbert sorry span is just an implementation of range. I'm working through the book Programming Elixir and the author had us create our own implementation of range (really just creates a list covering the range), but if I change calls to span to ranges, its the same effect.

Comment: `for x <- 2..10, y <- 2..10, x <= y, x * y <= n, into: [], do: x * y` does have duplicates if you see carefully.

Comment: @Dogbert Oh, I guess I didn't even notice that before. Thanks for that epiphany, but do you have any idea how to actually sort a comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon further reading, the solution is to encompass the comprehension in parentheses before piping.

```
(for x <- span(2, n), y <- span(2, n), x <= y, x * y <= n, into: [], do: x * y)
  |> Enum.sort
```

The above code is the solution. Parentheses are not needed when piping comprehensions in block format, but inline comprehensions require parentheses.

I discovered this by reading: [Elixir: error when piping to a function the result of inline comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402572/elixir-error-when-piping-to-a-function-the-result-of-inline-comprehension)

I did not discover this question prior to my posting although I searched Elixir comprehension, as I was not aware of the term 'inline comprehension'.